# Is there a way to prevent passing readonly params into non-readonly functions?

Tags: typescript, tslint

I was trying to ensure that an object that I use isn't modified, but I was surprised to see that it seems that typescript allows readonly objects to be passed in to functions which do not specify that the parameters are readonly. For example:

```
function testFunc1(obj: { readonly s: string }) {
  testFunc2(obj)   // no error <- would expect an error here as well
  obj.s = "blah"  // error: Cannot assign to 's' because it is a constant or a read-only property.
}

function testFunc2(obj: {s: string}) {
  obj.s = "blah"
}
```

Is it possible to turn on a setting or something so that an error would occur in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such setting, nor any workaround that I'm aware of.  See the [open suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13347).  It might be possible to write a tslint rule for this, but one would need to essentially duplicate the assignability checking logic in order to check for `readonly` in all the right places.  It might be more practical to use a modified version of the TypeScript compiler.